# Returning the last two set of records mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

well, i'm new to MySQL Database and i got a problem, i need to get the last two set of records from a table ( the records are automatically added to this table every week) i need to use to find the growth that an entity did during the last week.

can any one help plz.

here is what i wrote, i tested it on my local host and it worked :D, but when we installed it online, it crashed :(

```
select pages.*, new.* from (
select id, tableone.page_id, one, two,(two - one) as diff from 
(SELECT id, page_id, likes as two FROM `page_records` WHERE id IN ( SELECT max( id )    FROM `page_records` GROUP BY page_id )) as tableone left join 
(SELECT page_id , likes as one  FROM `page_records` where id in ( SELECT max(id) FROM   `page_records` where id not in (select max(id) from `page_records` group by page_id) group      by page_id))
as tabletwo 
on tableone.page_id = tabletwo.page_id 
order by tableone.page_id asc) as new inner join pages on pages.id = new.page_id
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 2

Comment: @SibirajPR plz, can you explain more?

Comment: If we need last two rows of a select query then we need to use ORDER By {auto increment field) DESC LIMIT 2.

Comment: @Strawberry Please explain...

Comment: thank you, but it seems my question is not clear enough. what i need is to get is the last two sets. this table is used to save the records of another one.

Comment: The OP's query is abysmal.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us from which tables and which field you need to get data, and what is considered a set, if the answer I gave below is not what you need?

Comment: @JelleFerwerda thank you, well i have two tables one i use to sotre entities and another table to store entities records. each week a new record is inserted for each entity. i need to calculate  the growth that each entity accomplished for the past week. using the records.

Comment: So.. Is this reliable, one entry per entity per week? Could you then not just select based on inserted date > 2 weeks ago, sort by entity, date? Personally, I would do this, and the do the growth calculations in PHP, post-retrieval.

Comment: @JelleFerwerda what about sorting entities based on their growth? any mysql solution please?

Comment: Sorry; I am not good with the elegant solutions.. My sites are mostly low-traffic sites. I whip a comparison function up in 5 minutes. Complex SQL always gets hairy when I try it and I spend days getting them to work.

Answer (score 2):

try:
    SELECT id, page_id, likes FROM `page_records` order by id desc limit 0, 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 0, 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: i have two tables one i use to sotre entities and another table to store entities records. each week a new record is inserted for each entity. i need to calculate the growth that each entity accomplished for the past week. using the records. so this won't work with me but thanks for your help.